# How to add AllowEncodedSlashes On to httpd.conf Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, httpd.conf

how to add AllowEncodedSlashes On in httpd.conf?

im using Apache/2.4.18 ...

i cant find httpd.conf in /etc/apache2

im read this article saying that httpd.conf no more https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

then, how i can add that AllowEncodedSlashes On?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all parameters have to be there, some have defaults  and do not need to be explicitaly defined, and some others are not needed by default either. So define it in the context you need it and see if it does what you expect.

According to the official docs its default is "off" so if not specified that's what you are getting.

Also valid to be defined in server config and virtualhost context only.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes